# AlarmManager with non specific time intervals

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Can anybody tell me how I can develop an `AlarmManager` that will report it self with non specified time intervals?

For example, the first alarm is at 12:00am, the second will be its 1:00am, the third will be 3:00am, the fourth will be 8:00am, the fifth alarm will be the next day, and the sixth alarm will after two days.

Comment: Do you mean a random time interval?

Comment: Perhaps just have each Alarm scheduled to run once, and once the first occurs, cancel it and schedule the next for the time that you prefer?

Comment: yes i was lookin for random time interval..
Guykun.. can you explain to me how i will cancel and than again re schedule the event...?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I have got. `alarmtTime` is a `String` array with time in Unix time stamp.

```
for(int i =0; i < alarmtTime.length; i++) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MeetMeInvitation.this, MyAlarmService.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MeetMeInvitation.this, i, myIntent, 0);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Long.parseLong(alarmtTime[i]),
                     pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: Just change the part where you add 10 seconds to add a Random (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random.html) amount of time. Be sure to cancel() (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#cancel()) the pending intent before setting it again with the AlarmManager.

Comment: this is just to tell the user and i have told above time is Unix formate and AlarmTime string is up to the user how he/she will set the reminder time with its non specific time interval.
in this code calendar is no more needed